# Laravel6 Passport accessToken revoke customly

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, laravel-6, laravel-passport

I am Doing laravel api based project where i am disabling the access token on a logout api just doing `revoke => 1` and i have to show the login detais of that user basically the `device/browser/ip` etc

In logout i am revoking that token manually by that method but when it comes a senario like if a user close the browser then the token is disabled by the set time in `AuthServiceProvider.php`

```
$this->registerPolicies();
Passport::routes(); 
Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5));
Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5));
Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(30));
```

My Logout

```
public function logOut($type) {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $token = Auth::user()->token();
            $data = Token::where('user_id',$user->id)
                          ->where('id', $token->id)
                          ->where('name', $type)
                          ->first();
            $data->update(['revoked' => 1, 'expires_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()]);            
            $response = [
                'status' => true,
                'message' => 'Successfully Logged Out',
            ];
            return response()->json($response); //@ sending response
        } else {
            $response = [
                    'status' => false,
                    'message' => 'Bad Request!',
            ];
            return response()->json($response); //@ sending response
        }                     
    }
```

Here the token is expiring after 5 mininutes `[returning 401 unauthenticated]` but the `revoke` is still remains 0

My question is how to do the token expire as well as the `revoke => 1` where `AuthServiceProvider` doing it??
I am Thinking about to do it using cron! Will it be okey?

Thanks!